# npm install doesn't run in my Ionic Project Directory

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework

After the creation of a new ionic project (in Windows 7) with

```
ionic start NewProject
```

I've to manually install into @ionic "app-scripts" folder, but when I try to install it with npm I get the error:

```
fatal error C1083: Impossible to open the include file 'stdbool.h': No such file or directory <..\..\src\libsass\src\ecc>
```

And

```
error code ELIFECYCLE
error errno 1
error node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
error Exit status 1
error Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.
error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What I have to doing for solve this trouble?

Comment: What is your nodeJS and npm versions? Also, which ionic version are you using? Enter `node -v` and `npm -v` , paste the outputs here.

Comment: Hi, versions are: node v9.3.0, npm v5.6.0, ionic 3.19.0

Comment: Latest Node version seems incompatible with ionic as of now. Try downloading Node v7.9.0 with the npm version you get with that node installation. Let us know if the issue gets resolved.

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you so much @clu3Less, but it's impossibile to work with Ionic whit the latest releases of nodejs and npm? 
What does it mean to work with these old versions? Are there any particular features that I will not be able to use?

Comment: Great. Please upvote my comment if I have helped. Thank you.